# how to find ip address of all connected clients in multi-client/server application in java?

Tags: java

i have created a simple multi-client/server app in java.
and i want to get the list of all connected clients.
how can i get the ip address of all connected clients?
i referred and tried code on this [creating simple client/server app](http://irate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html)
link for creating simple app

server Code:

```
public class ChatServer implements Runnable
{ 
      private ServerSocket     server = null;
      private Thread           thread = null;
      private ChatServerThread client = null;

      public ChatServer(int port)
      {  try

         {  System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
            server = new ServerSocket(port);  
            System.out.println("Server started: " + server);
            start();
         }
         catch(IOException ioe)
         {  System.out.println(ioe); }

      }
     public void run()
     {  while (thread != null)
        {  try
           {  System.out.println("Waiting for a client ..."); 
              addThread(server.accept());
           }
           catch(IOException ie)
           {  System.out.println("Acceptance Error: " + ie); }
         }
     }

    public void addThread(Socket socket)
    {   System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
        client = new ChatServerThread(this, socket);
        try
        {  client.open();
           client.start();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {  System.out.println("Error opening thread: " + ioe); }
    }

    public void start()                  
    public void stop()                    
    public static void main(String args[])
```

}

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to print the addresses out, simply change:

```
System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
```

To:

```
System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
```

If you want to keep a list of connected clients, simply add `socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()` to an `ArrayList`, or whatever data structure you like the most.

Comment: i'l try this...@neutrino thnx a lot :)